# AutoMapper does not ignore List when mapping from source to existing destination

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm having a small problem with AutoMapper. I have isolated the issue I am facing, if it actually is an issue and not just a misunderstanding.

Here are the classes I am working with:

```cs
public class DemoEntity
{
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DemoDto
{
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DemoProfile : Profile
{
    public DemoProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<DemoDto, DemoEntity>()
            .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
    }
}
```

In the Dependency Injection part (which seems to be in Program.cs for .NET 6, but is in Startup.cs in my main project), I have this code which I have read that should help allow nullable collections:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(configAction => { configAction.AllowNullCollections = true; }, typeof(Program));
```

Here is my test-code:

```cs
var dto = new DemoDto();
var entity = new DemoEntity()
{
    Items = new List<string>() { "Some existing item" },
    Name = "Existing name"
};

// Works as expected
var newEntity = _mapper.Map<DemoEntity>(dto);

// Sets the entity.Items to an empty list
_mapper.Map(dto, entity);
```

As you can see in the DemoProfile constructor, I set a condition to only map if `srcMember != null`, which works for the `Name` property. With the `AllowNullCollections` in the service registration, I can map to a new object with a null list (would be an empty list without the `AllowNullCollections` part).

My expected outcome would be AutoMapper to see that `dto.Items` is null, and not touch the `entity.Items` property during the mapping, and leave it with 1 string in the list. The actual outcome is that `entity.Items` is a list with 0 items. `Name` property is ignored.

Am I missing something? How can I adjust my code to work so that AutoMapper ignores a list that is null during mapping on an existing destination?

Answer (score 1):

You can look for [PreCondition](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html#preconditions) to prevent the mapping from source when the source's member (with the array, List) is null or empty.

```cs
CreateMap<DemoDto, DemoEntity>() 
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Items, opt => opt.PreCondition((source, dest) => 
    {
        return source.Items != null && source.Items.Count > 0;
    }))
    .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
```

[Sample demo on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E44bNR)

Comment: This seems to work, and I will use this as a workaround for now :) Thanks! But I will have to remember to add this PreCondition to all properties that contains a list. Is there a more generic way? And do you have any clue as to why my code is not working?

Comment: Hmmm, as I previously tried `PreCondition` is not possible as your requirement (Please correct me if I wrong). I think the array field not working correctly as [by default Automapper will assign empty array to destination if the source value was null](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html#handling-null-collections).